# ¿Por qué no se muestra un componente de Vue en una vista de Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, componentes

Quiero que los componentes que creo en Vue se muestren en Laravel, pero no sucede ningún cambio. La pagina se queda en blanco, pero si pongo cualquier otra cosa que no sea el componente, si realiza ese cambio. E incluso muestra los cambios si pongo los componentes en el mismo archivo de vista de Laravel.

Código de la Vista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código del Componente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código de App.Js

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya he corrido npm run dev y php artisan server. Y aun así no hay cambios. Si me puede ayudar lo agradecería

Comment: Si abrís la consola del explorador ves algún error de JS? Publicá el código de tu "webpack.mic.js". Por otro lado, te pido por favor que reemplaces todas las imágenes que subiste por texto. Es molesto tener que revisar el código así.

Answer (score 0):

Si estas ejecutado laravel mix?
Si lo estas ejecutando solo añade el componente completo y en kebab-case por ejemplo

```
<example-component></example-component>
```